# VB.NET - Find a Char followed by a period and remove the periods

Tags: string, vb.net, character

In VB.NET can you help me to figure out how to convert the char with period (or any abbreviation)

In the 4 samples below when you enter strings it will get the first letter and if there is a abbreviation it will remove the dots but will get all the letters. Thanks!

**See samples below:**

Enter in textbox:

Stack S. P.S Overflow

S. Stack P.S

A.B.C Stack Overflow Z.

Stack Z.

**Output:**

SSPSO

SSPS

ABCSOZ

SZ

Usage: ?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to do this. Otherwise it is very hard to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expressions seem to meet your needs:

```
Dim r = Regex.Replace("A.B.C Stack Overflow Z.", "[^A-Z]", "") 

MsgBox(r) 'shows ABCSOZ
```

This `"[^A-Z]"` is a pattern matcher meaning *"any character not in the range A-Z"*

This means all characters that are not an uppercase ASCII letter are replaced with an empty string

Comment: Or something like: `string.Concat([Line of Text].Where(c => char.IsUpper(c)))`, so it would include chars like e.g., `Ȗ Å Ğ` etc. (unless those are also meant to be excluded, that is).

Comment: There are indeed many ways to skin this cat; in the question as stated, accented characters do not appear to be under consideration.. Then again, the spec stated in the question does not agree with the title!

Comment: Thank you @CaiusJard I will try it  and thanks to All for checking